How to iterate through diagonals in a checkerboard checking whether a piece can capture with JavaScript
I have a designed a simple JavaScript board with CSS, HTML and JavaScript. The board has pieces at the top that can capture downwards either in the right or left direction. I am trying to code a function that can check if a tapped piece can jump over an opponent piece. For single captures,  this is simple because it involves just checking if the adjacent cells to the piece have an opponent piece which is encapsulated by empty cells, but for multiple captures then it becomes a little bit more problematic because it suggests that I need a loop that checks for a capture pattern and waits for the user to tap each empty square up until the last one and move that piece over that cell.
How do I do that in Java Script?


let A = true;
let B = false;
//define views that we will use to send messages to both players
let messageForA = document.getElementById("playerA");
let messageForB = document.getElementById("playerB");

//this function checks if the tapped piece can make single or multiple jumps over opponent cells
function canJumpOverOpponent(table, row, col) {
  /*a piece can jump over opponent pieces if there is an opponent piece
  between that piece and an empty square
  we use a path finding algorithm to check for empty squares in the path of that piece
  */
  //the top pieces can either capture left or right downwards


}
//this function draws the chekerboard

function createCheckerboard() {
  const table = document.getElementById('checkertable');
  for (let row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
    const newRow = table.insertRow();
    for (let col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
      const newCell = newRow.insertCell();
      newCell.classList.add('square');
      if ((row + col) % 2 === 0) {
        //paint the white squares
        newCell.classList.add('white');
      } else {
        //paint the brow squares where we will draw pieces
        newCell.classList.add('brown');
        //we draw the old pieces in this section
        if (row < 3) {
          const goldpiece = document.createElement('div');
          goldpiece.classList.add('gold-piece');;
          newCell.appendChild(goldpiece);
          goldpiece.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            if (A) {
              if (event.target.classList.contains('gold-piece')) {
                //means the cell contains a piece
                console.log("This square contains a gold piece");
                //highlight this piece and remove highlights from any previous square
                const goldpieces = document.querySelectorAll('.gold-piece');
                console.log(goldpieces.length);
                goldpieces.forEach(function(element) {
                  if (element.classList.contains('selected-piece')) {
                    //remove the highlight from previous cells
                    element.classList.remove('selected-piece');
                  }
                });
                event.target.classList.add('selected-piece');
                //check if the piece can make a jump over opponent pieces


              } else {
                //this square is empty 
                console.log("this piece is empty, check if user had tapped a previous square or he is completing a capture");
              }
            } else {
              console.log("player one attempts to play while it is not his turn");
            }
          });
        }
        //we draw the red pieces in this section
        if (row >= 5) {
          const redpiece = document.createElement('div');
          redpiece.classList.add('red-piece');;
          newCell.appendChild(redpiece);
        }

      }

    }
  }
}
window.onload = () => createCheckerboard();
body {
  background: green;
}


/*style the table*/

.table {
  margin: auto;
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
}

.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.white {
  background-color: mintcream;
}

.brown {
  background-color: chocolate;
}


/*styles for the pieces*/

.gold-piece {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background-color: gold;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 10%;
}

.red-piece {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background-color: orangered;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 10%;
}


/*style for styling a selected piece*/

.selected-piece {
  border: 2px solid white;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="playerA"></div>
  <table id="checkertable"></table>
  <div id="playerA"></div>
</body>

</html>




Can someone edit to make this page display the board here so other developers can visualize what I am trying to achieve?

My idea, if found a capture, is to run the same function again to find captures from the new point. This assumes only forward moves, and not allow partial captures.


var board = [
  [ 0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1],
  [ 1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0],
  [ 0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1],
  [-1,  0, -1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
  [-1,  0, -1,  0, -1,  0, -1,  0],
  [ 0,  0,  0, -1,  0,  0,  0, -1],
  [-1,  0, -1,  0, -1,  0, -1,  0],
]

function printBoard(board) {
  var str = ""
  for (var i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
      str += (board[i][j] < 0 ? " " : "  ") + board[i][j]
    }
    str += "\n"
  }
  console.log(str)
}

function getCell(board, cellY, cellX) {
  if (cellY < 0 || cellX < 0 || cellY >= board.length || cellX >= board[0].length) {
    return null
  }
  return board[cellY][cellX]
}

// top left 0, 0
function getCaptures(board, cellY, cellX) {
  var result = [];

  for (var j = -1; j <= 1; j += 2) {
    if (getCell(board, cellY + 1, cellX + j) === -1 && getCell(board, cellY + 2, cellX + j + j) === 0) {

      var nextMoves = getCaptures(board, cellY + 2, cellX + j + j)
      if (nextMoves.length == 0) {
        result.push([cellY + 2, cellX + j + j])
      } else {
        result = result.concat(nextMoves)
      }
    }
  }
  return result
}

printBoard(board)
var result = getCaptures(board, 2, 1)
console.log("moves from [2, 1]: " + JSON.stringify(result))




Great answer, but would be more useful if you could edit so I can test it and see if its working

you can edit the 2d array board and use printBoard function to test, if that is what you mean
